# How to employe auto-deployment?

Tags: weblogic12c

I'm working on a WLS 12.1c locally installed application server (on a VM instance). I deployed apps with the help of the WLS web console. Selecting "install" and selecting the path of the EAR file I wish to deploy. Fine. Works.

However, I wish that the ear is picked up from this same place every time it changes. Otherwise I have to "Delete" the deployment package, restart the server and "install" the EAR again. Too much hassle.

How do I activate auto-deployment?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in a development setting, you might want to use auto-deployment instead:

> Development mode enables a WebLogic Server instance to automatically deploy and update applications that are in the domain_name/autodeploy directory (where domain_name is the name of a WebLogic Server domain).

Note that your Weblogic Server MUST be running in development mode.
Once you add your EAR to `domain_name/autodeploy/`, from there on out, it will automatically picks up changes to the files in that directory:

> To auto-deploy an archived application, copy its archive file to the /autodeploy directory. WebLogic Server automatically sets the application's deployment mode to stage mode.
>
> A deployment unit that was auto-deployed can be dynamically redeployed while the server is running. To dynamically redeploy, copy the new version of the archive file over the existing file in the /autodeploy directory.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/autodeploy.htm

Comment: I just wonder CAN one change the autodeploy directory or not? I skimmed the documentation and did NOT find any hints on that.

Comment: Probably not. Just make a target in your ant file or something for deploy that copies or links it to the right folder is the easier way to get it to work. Personally, I use WLST to do my undeploy/deploy handling in a script, and it is part of my build process.